# Spring Integration: JDBC single query to web service

Tags: spring-mvc, soap, integration, spring-integration, spring-ws

I would like to know the way for resolving this integration scenario:

- Execute different queries to select X elements from a database. I am
  looking for an inbound adapter without pooling because it is just
  necessary to execute the query once. Although, results of the queries
  will be generate only one output.
- Work with this data to build a SOAP request (generic web service)
- Send this SOAP request to a web service and wait for an asynchronous response.

But also, it is necessary to deploy all this scenario in a WAR file on Tomcat server. I am deploying the application from a spring MVC + spring integration skeleton but I will not have any controller. Is it possible to execute the application when context was loaded on Tomcat?

I am working with the next technologies:

- Spring integration
- Spring MVC for a WAR deployment
- Scheduling (Quartz or @Scheduled)
- Spring WS

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you'd prefer to `select` on the application start up and only once, you can use:

```
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="jdbcChannel" 
       event-types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent"
       payload-expression="''"/>
```

and `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway query="SELECT * FROM ..."/>`

And so on to the WebService.

**UPDATE**

Since you say that you are around Anotation configuration, consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl).

To configure `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter>` from `@Configuration` you should do this:

```
    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MessageProducer ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer() {
        ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer producer = new ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer();
        producer.setEventTypes(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        producer.setPayloadExpression("''");
        producer.setOutputChannel(jdbcChannel());
        return producer;
    }
```

`ContextRefreshedEvent` info you can get from its JavaDocs or from [Spring Framework Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events).

Comment: Thanks Artem. The outbound-gateway seems to be a good solution. As I am working only with annotated configuration, could you indicate where can I found more info about ContextRefreshedEvent?

Comment: Added a sample for Annotation configuration variant.

Comment: An what about: <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway query="SELECT * FROM ..."/> with annotations. I am trying to create a JdbcOutboundGateway but I get 'no suscribers' exception

Comment: :-). Since it is difinatelly separete question, let's start a new thread! Don't worry, I monitor all `spring-integration` questions